# Image styling not showing properly in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm really confused as to what i'm doing wrong here.. Anytime I call for the stylesheet to handle styling for this particular image nested in View, i have to declare its dimensions within the actual jsx. Sorry If i'm using any terminology wrong I'm new to react native.

Here's my code that's NOT displaying the image:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.restaurantContainer}>

        <Image 
        source = {{ uri:"http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19632.png" }} 
        style = { styles.image }/> 

      </View>
<StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',

    image: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,

    }, 

    restaurantContainer: {
        width: "100%",


    },
  },
});
```

here's the code that displays the image fine

```
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.restaurantContainer}>

        <Image 
        source = {{ uri:"http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19632.png" }} 
        style = {{ height:100, width:100 }}/> 

      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image` style is nested within the `container` style, which is why it is not found when calling `styles.image`. The `image` and `restaurantContainer` style should be defined at the same level as `container` like this:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
  restaurantContainer: {
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```